# Apollo Server WebSocket Connection Docker Compose Expose Problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I am trying to develop an app with apollo graphql server and react. i susbscribe to apollo server from react container(visualization) and consume data. If i map ports of apollo server, i can connect to apollo server and react app works fine but if i expose port in docker compose file, connection fails. I cant understand why this happens, normally within the same network containers can talk each other and i haven't faced similar problems before

Compose File With Expose

[image]

Error

[image]

Compose File With Port

[image]

No Error works fine:

[image]

Comment: Solution to problem is as described in the link [Web Container Cannot Call Backend Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986908/web-container-cannot-call-backend-container-from-docker-compose)